# How to read a cell value from Excel that contains a function in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, io

I am writing a C# application that reads data from an Excel file. Everything was running smoothly until I attempted to read from a cell that used a formula.

I am pulling data from the sheet and trying to add the cumulative quantity, so in a loop, I'm using:

```
cntr = Cell(row, column);
```

**NOTE: I'm paraphrasing rather than copy my actual code.**

Anyways, if the actual cell value contains a number, this works, but if the cell contains a function, it returns the string

> "=SUM(A1:A5)"

and I'm not sure how I can execute this in my C# code to retrieve the actual value of that cell.

Comment: As a side note: Interop is really slow and error-prone, you might want to use a library like EPPLUS, this is ages faster than interop

Comment: I'll definitely look into that, likely for another project since I'm already so deep into this one. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Cell(a,b).Value
```

instead of just `Cell(a,b)`.

---

Also, the following approach should work

```
Excel.Range objRange = (Excel.Range)objSheet.Cells[rowN,colN];
variableName = objRange.get_Value(System.Missing.Type).ToString();
```

You may modify it for your datatype

Comment: I tried that approach, but for some reason I'm getting the error that the object does not contain a definition for 'Value'. Perhaps my interop file is wrong? I'm not sure what it's missing, or perhaps I really am missing an assembly reference.

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at this solution posted on SO earlier. Seems to be a similar problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714724/c-getting-a-cells-value-with-excel-interop

Comment: Same issue. I'm going to look over my interop file again and see if I am missing something.

Comment: Yup, lemme know if the new edit I posted works. If so that's great, else I'll delete this answer as it doesn't deserve +1 rep if it's not working.

Comment: It did. I was making a stupid mistake with my assembly references. I was using the namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and had no idea I could change it to say 'using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'. At first I received the error Excel was not defined.

The way I wrote it: variableName = (Cell(row, col) as Excel.Range).Value;

Thanks for your help!